# Drawing a pages border

Tags: tikz-pgf

Can you help me !!
how to make a border and vertical rectangle with chapter name and page number like this . Thank you

[image: page 1]

Comment: Welcome on this site. You'll probably need Tikz. Can you provide at least the content of the page as a minimal working example?

Comment: Look at package `tikz-page`.

Comment: First off, do you want your design to be flipped depending on odd/even page numbers?

Comment: @SebGlav yes i do , Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a rough example to show you how to use `tkz-page`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-page}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
    
\tikzset{
        secnode/.style={
                minimum height=1cm,
                inner xsep=20pt,
                rotate=90,
                anchor=north east,
                draw=white,
                fill=olive,
                text=white,
                blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5,shadow blur extra rounding=1.3pt}},
        pagenode/.style={
                minimum width=5mm,
                minimum height=1cm,
                inner sep=2pt,
                anchor=south east,
                draw=white,
                fill=olive,
                text=white,
                blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5,shadow blur extra rounding=1.3pt}}
        }
\newcommand{\tikzpagelayout}{
        \draw[olive,line width=2pt,rounded corners=20pt] ([xshift=5mm]page.northwest) |- ([xshift=-2cm,yshift=5mm]page.southeast);
        \node[secnode] at (page.northwest) {Chapitre 05.\quad FONCTIONS LOGARTITHMES};
        \node[pagenode] at ([xshift=-1cm]page.southeast) {1};
      }
         
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

which produces:
[image: tkz-page]

Now, you have to adapt some things. I did not use neither `\thesection` nor `\thepage` here, but you will have to add it into your nodes declarations.

If you want to have odd/even pages, you have to create two different codes with `\tpflip{<odd>}{<even>}`. If you still struggle with that, feel free to ask another question.

Comment: Thank you so much it's very helpful

Comment: I saw in the documentation that the package uses fancyhdr internally. So am I right in assuming that it will throw errors with Koma classes?