# Drawing a border in odd and even pages

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

Please help me for having this border different in odd / even pages

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-page}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
    
\tikzset{
        secnode/.style={
                minimum height=1cm,
                inner xsep=20pt,
                rotate=90,
                anchor=north east,
                draw=white,
                fill=olive,
                text=white,
                blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5,shadow blur extra rounding=1.3pt}},
        pagenode/.style={
                minimum width=5mm,
                minimum height=1cm,
                inner sep=2pt,
                anchor=south east,
                draw=white,
                fill=olive,
                text=white,
                blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5,shadow blur extra rounding=1.3pt}}
        }
\newcommand{\tikzpagelayout}{
        \draw[olive,line width=2pt,rounded corners=20pt] ([xshift=5mm]page.northwest) |- ([xshift=-2cm,yshift=5mm]page.southeast);
        \node[secnode] at (page.northwest) {Chapitre 05.\quad FONCTIONS LOGARTITHMES};
        \node[pagenode] at ([xshift=-1cm]page.southeast) {1};
      }
         
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it a question related to this? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/599026/drawing-a-pages-border

Comment: @Sebastiano Yes

Comment: Seem that what you want is possible with the command `\tpflip` of the `tikz-page` package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like I said, use `\tpflip` to design both eve and odd page styles.
[image: tkz-page with even and odd pages]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-page}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
    
\tikzset{
        secnode/.style={
                minimum height=1cm,
                inner xsep=20pt,
                rotate=90,
                anchor=north east,
                draw=white,
                fill=olive,
                text=white,
                blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5,shadow blur extra rounding=1.3pt}},
        pagenode/.style={
                minimum width=5mm,
                minimum height=1cm,
                inner sep=2pt,
                anchor=south east,
                draw=white,
                fill=olive,
                text=white,
                blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5,shadow blur extra rounding=1.3pt}}
        }
\newcommand{\tikzpagelayout}{
        \tpflip{
            \draw[olive,line width=2pt,rounded corners=20pt] ([xshift=5mm]page.northwest) |- ([xshift=-2cm,yshift=5mm]page.southeast);
            \node[secnode] at (page.northwest) {Chapitre 05.\quad FONCTIONS LOGARTITHMES};
            \node[pagenode] at ([xshift=-1cm]page.southeast) {1};
            }
            {
            \draw[olive,line width=2pt,rounded corners=20pt] ([xshift=-5mm]page.northeast) |- ([xshift=2cm,yshift=5mm]page.southwest);
            \node[secnode,anchor=south east] at (page.northeast) {Chapitre 05.\quad FONCTIONS LOGARTITHMES};
            \node[pagenode,anchor=south west] at ([xshift=1cm]page.southwest) {1};
            }
      }
         
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-14]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Added my upvote for your long effort. Very nice answer and also for the related question.

Comment: @SebGlav Thank youuuuu